# Creating .wav files of varying pitches but still having the same fundamental frequency

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am using pygame to play .wav files and want to change the pitch of a particular .wav file as each level in my game progresses. To explain, my game is a near copy of the old Oric1 computer OricMunch Pacman game, where there are a few hundred pills to be munched on each level, and for every pill that is munched a short sound is played, with the pitch of the sound increasing slightly for each pill eaten/munched.

**Now here is what I have tried**:

1) I have used pythons wave module to create multiple copies of the sound file, each newly created file having a slight increase in pitch (by changing the 3rd parameter in params() the framerate, sometimes referred to as the sample frequency) for each cycle of a for loop. Having achieved this, I could then within the loop create multiple sound objects to add to a list, and then index through the list to play the sounds as each pill is eaten.

The problem is even though I can create hundreds of files (using the wave module) that play perfectly with their own unique pitches when played using windows media player, or even pythons winsound module, pygame does not seem to interpret the difference in pitch.

Now interestingly, I have downloaded the free trial version of **[Power Sound Editor](http://www.free-sound-editor.com/download.html)** which has the option to change the pitch, and so I’ve created just a few .wav files to test, and they clearly play with different pitches when played in pygame.

**Observations**:
From printing the params in my for loop, I can see that the framerate/frequency is changing as intended, and so obviously this is why the sounds play as intended through windows media player and winsound.

Within pygame I suspect the reason they don’t play with different pitches is because the frequency parameter is fixed, either to the default settings or via the use of pygame.mixer.pre_init, which I have indeed experimented with.
I then checked the params for each .wav file created by the Power Sound Editor, and noticed that even though the pitch sound was changing, the frequency stayed the same, which is not totally surprising since you have to select 1 of 3 options to save the files, either 22050, 44100 or 96000Hz

So now I thought time to check out the difference between pitch and frequency specifically in relation to sound, since I thought they were the same. What I found was it seems there are two principle aspects of sound waves: 1) The framerate/frequency And 2) The varying amplitude of multiple waves based on that frequency. Now I far from clearly understand this, but realise the Power Sound Editor must be altering the shape/pitch of the sound by manipulating the varying amplitude of multiple waves, point 2) above, and not by changing the fundamental frequency, point 1) above.

I am a beginner to python, pygame and programming in general, and have tried hard to find a simple way to change sound files to have gradually increasing pitches without changing the framerate/fundamental frequency. If there’s a module that I can import to help me change the pitch by manipulating the varying amplitude of mutiple waves (instead of changing the framerate/sample frequency which typically is either 22050 or 44100Hz), then it needs to take relatively no time at all if being done on the fly in order to not slow the game down. If the potential module opens, changes and then saves sound files, as opposed to altering them on the fly, then I guess it does not matter if it’s slow because I will just be creating the sound files so I can create sound objects from them in pygame to play.

Now if the only way to achieve no slow down in pygame is to create sound objects from sound files as I have already done, and then play them, then I need a way to manipulate the sound files like the Power Sound Editor (again I stress not by changing the framerate/sample frequency of typically 22050 or 44100) and then save the changed file.

I suppose in a nut shell, if I could magically automate Power Sound Editor to produce 3 to 4 hundred sound files without me having to click on the change pitch option and then save each time, this would be like having my own python way of doing it.

**Conclusion**:
Assuming creating sound objects from sound files is the only way not to slow my game down (as I suspect it might be) then I need the following:

An equivalent to the python wave module, but which changes the pitch like Power Sound Editor does, and not by changing the fundamental frequency like the wave module does.

Please can someone help me and let me know if there’s a way.

I am using python 3.2.3 and pygame 1.9.2

Also I’m just using pythons IDLE and I’m not familiar with using other editors.

Also I’m aware of Numpy and of various sound modules, but definitely don’t know how to use them. Also any potential modules would need to work with the above versions of python and pygame.

Thank you in advance.

Gary Townsend.

**My Reply To The First Answer From Andbdrew Is Below:**

Thank you for your assistance.

It does sound like changing the wave file data rather than the wave file parameters is what I need to do. For reference here is the code I have used to create the multiple files:

```
framerate = 44100 #Original .wav file framerate/sample frequency

for x in range(0, 25):    
   file = wave.open ('MunchEatPill3Amp.wav')   
   nFrames = file.getnframes()
   wdata = file.readframes(nFrames) 
   params = file.getparams()     
   file.close()

   n = list(params)   
   n[0] = 2 
   n[2] = framerate

   framerate += 500 

   params = tuple(n)    
   name = 'PillSound' + str(x) + '.wav'     

   file = wave.open(name, 'wb')
   file.setparams(params)
   print(params)
   file.writeframes(wdata)
   file.close()
```

It sounds like writing different data would be equivalent or similar to how the Power Sound Editor is changing the pitch.

So please can you tell me if you know a way to modify/manipulate wdata to effectively change the pitch, rather than alter the sample rate in params(). Would this mean some relatively simple operation applied to wdata after it’s read from my .wav file. (I really hope so) I’ve heard of using numpy arrays, but I have no clue how to use these.

Please note that any .wav files modified in the above code, do indeed play in Python using winsound, or in windows media player, with the pitch increase sounding as intended. It’s only in Pygame that they don’t.

As I’ve mentioned, it seems because Pygame has a set frequency (I guess this frequency is also sample rate), that this might be the reason the pitch sounds the same, as if it wasn’t increased at all. Whereas when played with e.g. windows media player, the change in sample rate does result in a higher sounding pitch.

I suppose I just need to achieve the same increase in pitch sound by changing the file data, and not the file parameters, and so please can you tell me if you know a way.

Thank you again for helping with this.

**To Summarise My Initial Question Overall, Here It Is Again:**

How do you change the pitch of a .wav file without changing the framerate/sample frequency, by using the python programming language, and not some kind of separate software program such as Power Sound Editor?

Thank You Again.

Comment: BTW never heard of Power Sound Editor, but Audacity is your Gimp equivalent for sound editing - most popular among free open-source software

Answer (score 1):

You should change the frequency of the wave in your sample instead of changing the sample rate. It seems like python is playing back all of your wave files at the same sample rate (which is good), so your changes are not reflected.

Sample rate is sort of like meta information for a sound file. Read about it at http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_rate#mw-mf-search .

It tells you the amount of time between samples when you convert a continuous waveform into a discrete one. Although your (ab)use of it is cool, you would be better served by encoding different frequencies of sound in your different files all at the same sample rate.

I took a look at the docs for the wave module ( http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/wave.html ) and it looks like you should just write different data to your audio files when you call

```
 Wave_write.writeframes(data)
```

That is the method that actually writes your audio data to your audio file.

The method you described is responsible for writing information about the audio file itself, not the content of the audio data.

```
 Wave_write.setparams(tuple)
```

"... Where the tuple should be (nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes, comptype, compname), with values valid for the set*() methods. Sets all parameters... " ( also from the docs )

If you post your code, maybe we can fix it.

Comment: Please read my reply to the first answer from **Andbdrew**. You can find it added onto the end of my initial question. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create multiple files and you are using linux, try **SoX**.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq -20 10 20`; do
    sox 'input.wav' 'output_'$i'.wav' pitch $i;
done
```